# Cant access remote app after domain password reset

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-services, authentication

I have a domain user that uses a remote desktop app. I recently reset his password via AD and although he can log in to his account he cant authenticate against the remote app anymore.

Ive checked the Remote app manager and cant see any settings for individual passwords there (dont think there is one?)

Hes setup as a remote desktop user and accesses the app through an .rdp file on his desktop..Any suggestions as to what this may be?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I got the user to logout, reset their password and untick the 'change at next logon' requirement and log back in. This resolved their issue.